# Need advice with a menu with float that messes up other divs

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I've got a div at the top of my site that has a dropdown menu with a float to the left, the thing is that under that div where I want to have a header whenever I hover over the menu the header floats to the left as well.

I tried to do a clear div after the top div then on css use `clear:both`; but it didn't really help

Here's the JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Safushi/XRNP5/

```
ul {
font-size: 16px;
list-style: none;
}

ul li {
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

li ul {
display: none;
}

ul li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
background: #464646;
white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover {
background: #565656;
}
```

is some of the code for the menu (had to paste some code to be able to paste JSfiddle link).

Answer (score 1):

It will be fixed by adding a

```
 position: absolute;
```

to the ul that contains the submenu.

Answer (score 1):

The child `ul` element needs to be absolutely positioned if you don't want it to effect the other elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LsyJ2/)

```
#top li > ul {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

And as Adrift mentions, you may also want to give the `ul` a width of `100%`.

Comment: And add `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

You got the layer of HTML file right,but the property "position" wrong.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XRNP5/1/)

Once a tag's settled `position:absolute;` ,it will only be positioned referring to its containing block.So you need to set   `#menu{postion:relative;}` to let its parent-tag be the containing block.In fact,now the submenu is totally deleted from the normal flow,so it won't affect the styles of other tags.

Moreover,I **highly** recommend you to resist to use descendant selectors,which not only let your browser slower,and your code maintenance much more complex as well.